# Flutter: FutureBuilder срабатывает на другом view

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Есть `view A` и `view B`. 
На `А` есть `FutureBuilder`. 
Когда переходу из `view А` на `view B` через `Navigator.Push()` срабатывает функция которая прикреплена к `FutureBuilder` на `view A`. 
Мне не нужно чтобы срабатывал `FutureBuilder` если я не на `view` с `Futurebuilder`

**Это код "view A"(_StoriesState), когда я перехожу на B(StoryPage) вызывается функция getStories которую можно вызвать только в A(_StoriesState)**

```
    ............
Future<dynamic> getStories(int items, List<int> pickerSelectedIndex) async {
    try {
    ............
      return stories;
    } on HandshakeException catch (e) {
      print("HE: " + e.toString());
      getStories(items, pickerSelectedIndex);
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print("SE: " + e.toString());
      getStories(items, pickerSelectedIndex);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      getStories(items, pickerSelectedIndex);
    }
  }
............
class _StoriesState extends State<Stories> {

  Future<List<Story>> listViewData;
  ............
  Future<List<Story>> getStoriesDataReady(
      int items, List<int> pickerSelectedIndex) async {
    List<Story> stories = await getStories(items, pickerSelectedIndex);
    if (globals.filter.isEmpty) {
      return stories;
    } else {
      ............
      return searchStories;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: ............
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            listViewData =
                getStoriesDataReady(globals.items, pickerSelectedIndex);
            return Scaffold(
                body: FutureBuilder<List<Story>>(
                    future: listViewData,
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<List<Story>> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        ............
                        child: FloatingSearchBar.builder(
                            ............
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
                            itemBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              ............
                              onTap: () {
                                ............
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) => StoryPage(............)),
                                ).then((value) {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                });
                              }
                              ............
                        }),
                        ............
        });
  }
}
```

Подскажите, как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: Предоставьте код, как мы должны воспроизвести вашу ошибку и помочь вам?

Comment: @MiT слишком много кода

Comment: предоставьте нужную часть кода, мне не нужен весь проект...

Comment: @MiT предоставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Перенесите инициализацию `listViewData` в `initState` для того чтобы, инициализировать её единожды при создании виджета:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  listViewData = getStoriesDataReady(globals.items, pickerSelectedIndex);
}
```

2) У вас нет проблем с `snapshot` (имена одинаковые...)?

---

*Ответ дан исходя из предоставленного кода и информации. Возможно это не решит проблему, так как она может находиться где-то в другом месте...*

Comment: Срабатывает этот код когда перехожу на другой view 
Переместил присвоение в initState. if (snapshot.hasData) {
            listViewData =
                getStoriesDataReady(globals.items, pickerSelectedIndex);

Comment: @NoProgress что вы хотите этим сказать?

Comment: Мое непонимание, почему код на нижнем уровне Navigation продолжает работу когда перешел через push на новый уровень

Comment: @NoProgress потому что: 1) Future это результат асинхронной операций и может работать до тех пор пока не кончаться данные. 2) При переходе через push вы не уничтожаете код нижнего уровня (тем самым позволяете ему продолжать работать).